# PHP Crawler not working

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am using the below php code to extract the content under id=description using getElementByID

```
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    if(!$doc) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'Synopsis');
?>
```

In the above code when I use the inputs as ('www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'Synopsis') it is working fine but when I try for another website inputs `(www.lookupbyisbn.com/Lookup/Book/0143418769/0143418769/1, reviews)` it is not working... Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other website (www.lookupbyisbn.com/Lookup/Book/0143418769/0143418769/1) has an id called 'reviews' but still it is not woking :-(
PS: I am a beginner in php

Comment: When you are a php beginner then I am"impressed" by the way how your code looks like. I see here all the times a horrible programming style but your is OK! Voted up just for this.

Comment: What is the problem, is an exception thrown, are the contents of your variable not what you expect them to be, etc.?

Comment: Just a confirmation question: You are using quotes in the 2nd call? Here in the example they are missing.

Comment: Your script works fine for me if I you use "http://" for the URL , and if you change the `id` to `synopsis`. You probably want to just echo out any errors instead of throwing exceptions if you are just tinkering around. I was getting an uncaught fatal error in my test but didn't see it the first 20 times I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems second web url required some extra headers to fetch html content from the website. I suggest you to use curl to load remote content. Have a look on below solution, I made minor changes in your current code: ($doc->loadHTMLFile($url) is returning false for second web url)

```
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);


//    var_dump($doc->loadHTMLFile($url)); die;

    if(!$result) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }
    $doc->loadHTML($result);
    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('http://www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'synopsis');

echo getElementByIdAsString('http://www.lookupbyisbn.com/Lookup/Book/0143418769/0143418769/1', 'reviews');
```

Comment: @Iqbal: Yes, it seems the 2nd site is returning an empty page when the header is not a "browser". When you have problems just dump the output with `->saveHTML()` and then you see very fast what the problem may be.

Comment: Something I just learned: you can set the default user-agent php uses for http requests via INI, eg : `ini_set('user_agent', 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');`

Comment: @chetan Ameta The code you provided is throwing exception

Comment: @IqbalHonnur can you tell me what exception it's showing?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta There was a Fatal error, which stopped when I removed the ; in the C:\xampp\php\php.in before ;extension=php_curl.dll....Now It is working fine, but I see hell lot of warnings appearing on screen along with the content.

Comment: change error reporting to ERROR level so warning can be hide

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine, but you might spot the issues easier (for now) if you output the errors directly. I made some slight adjustments and it seems to work as expected:

```
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = $pretty;

    if( !$doc->loadHTMLFile($url) ) {
        echo  "Failed to load $url";
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    if( !( $element = $doc->getElementById($id) )) {
        echo  "An element with id $id was not found";
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}
```

So in your original example:

```
// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'Synopsis');
```

this outputs :

> Failed to load www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp

because URL-based file locations need to have the schema, eg http://. Updating for that in mind:

```
// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('http://www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'Synopsis');
```

Outputs:

> An element with id Synopsis was not found

This is because (drumroll please...) there isn't an element in that document with an id of `Synopsis`. Looking at the page source directly, I see an element with an id of `synopsis`, so adjusting again for this, I tried:

```
// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('http://www.abebooks.com/9780143418764/Love-Story-Singh-Ravinder-0143418769/plp', 'synopsis');'
```

Which returned:

```
<div role="tabpanel" id="synopsis" class="tab-pane active">&#13;
                    <div class="ms-toggle">&#13;
                      <p class="synopsis-item">Do Love stories ever die? Can modern day gadgets like Mobile phones and the http:\ www’ era of Internet bring you the love of your life? You haven't met her earlier, but commit to marry. Will you still call this a love marriage? And what if on the engagement day while you pull the ring out from your pocket, you realize what you planned was just a dream which never comes true...? How would you react when a beautiful person comes into your life, becomes your most precious possession and then one day goes away from you...forever? Not all love stories are meant to have a perfect ending. Some stay incomplete. Yet they are beautiful in their own way. Ravin's love story is one such innocent and beautiful story. He believes love stories seldom die. They are meant to stay for the generations yet to come and read them.</p>&#13;
                      <p id="synopsis-disclaimer-text"><em>"synopsis" may belong to another edition of this title.</em></p>&#13;
                    </div>&#13;
                  </div>
```

So your function itself seems fine (maybe a bit rough, but that's forgivable), you just need to actually pay attention to those errors you took the time to build in. You managed to hit both in your example: invalid URL, non-existent ID.

### Update:

As mentioned in another answer, the issue seems to be with the remote site not returning anything if the `User-Agent:` header isn't set for the HTTP request. As suggested, one option would be to use curl to fetch the remote HTML first, allowing for more control over the HTTP request. Another option would be to set the `user_agent` INI directive at runtime, like so:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
```

So in the case of your function, you would add:

```
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = $pretty;    

    ini_set('user_agent', 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');

    if( !$doc->loadHTMLFile( $url ) ) {
        echo  "Failed to load $url" . PHP_EOL;
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    if( !( $element = $doc->getElementById($id) )) {
        echo  "An element with id $id was not found" . PHP_EOL;
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}
```

I tested and this appears to work without having to switch over to curl (which is still a good idea in general).

Comment: Actually below is the exception I am getting
===========================================
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'An element with id reviews was not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php(35): getElementByIdAsString() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php on line 23
============================================


Element with id=reviews exists in (www.lookupbyisbn.com/Lookup/Book/0143418769/0143418769/1) still I am getting the exceptioin

Comment: I have modified the script to work..but I am unable to parse the content on wikipedi..is the site blocking the parser script? if so, is there any solutions I can parse the content from wikipedia